# Index Match based on 2 columns but 1 contains empty cells

Tags: excel

So I am currently trying to do a index match to find certain values based on month and year. It looks something like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Lsu.png)

I've tried few but none of them worked. This one sort of worked but only for the first year in column A, and gives reference error for the rest.

```
=INDEX(C1:C36,MATCH(H2,A1:A37,0)*MATCH(J2,B1:B36,0))
```

How can I fix this problem? Would there be a way to do a look up based on a column (cannot be edited) cells are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is sorted use:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(H2,A:A,0)+MATCH(J2,B:B,0)-1)
```

[image]